# C3.js: Tooltip on line beetwen points

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I have a specific chart:

[image]

and I would like to remove points and add tooltip to the line, because there is confusion when crossing lines

It seems that this cannot be done using standard library functions.
Does anyone know how to add a tooltip for the line?

i try to add event for line:

```
let line = d3.selectAll(".c3-line")
line.on("mouseover", function(){
  console.log('here');
})
```

to add custom tooltip - but no one event for line not works

Comment: Which points do you want to be removed? The grid ? The points with colors ?

Comment: @Wandrille points on line

Comment: @Wandrille remove point not a problem. Problem - add tooltip for line

Comment: Can you provide the code of your D3js graph ?

Comment: @Wandrille i added little changes. As exsample for chart i use https://c3js.org/samples/simple_multiple.html

Answer (score 1):

You can remove points drastically with:

```
selectAll('svg circle').remove()
```

Comment: Problem - add tooltip for line

Comment: @Lola Take a look at how it is done [here](https://github.com/wandri/wandrille-guesdon.com/blob/master/src/app/graph/graphs/line-chart/line-chart.component.ts). The `generateTipOnMouseOver` function